# WP 3.4 - what action/hook is called when theme customisation is saved?

Tags: theme-development, themes

i'm looking for the action/hook called when saving theme customs colors in the new admin interface?

i need to call a custom function to save a set of php generated images.

if anyone have clues... :)

thanks

Comment: The customize_save action in wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php might be what you're looking for. Although I was able to save arbitrary data to the DB on that hook when clicking save in the customizer, I wasn't able to get at any of the actual fields in the customizer. I'm curious about that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings are saved via ajax, with the action `customize_save`. In the `wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php` class, the callback for this ajax method is the `save` method ([see source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L462))

This triggers the `customize_save` action, prior to updating each of the settings.

Each setting is actually an instance of the class [`WP_Customize_Setting`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-setting.php) and saving the setting triggers the action

```
customize_save_{$setting_id}
```

if you wanted to trigger the action when a particular setting is saved (unfortunately there's no filter).

The `save` method calls the `update` method, which behaves different depending on whether the settings is a 'theme_mod' or 'option'. Regardless they are both saved using `update_option` (and so passed through the appropriate filters). The former is done so via [`set_theme_mod()`](http://queryposts.com/function/set_theme_mod/).